# How to add html checkbox,radiobutton,textbox in pdf using itextstarp?

Tags: pdf, model-view-controller, itext

How to add html checkbox,radiobutton,textbox in pdf using itextstarp.Am using this code.

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        var viewData = ViewData;

        ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, "ABCDFORM", null);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewEngineResult.View, viewData, new TempDataDictionary(), stringWriter);
        viewEngineResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);

        // Get the view HTML string
        string htmlToConvert = stringWriter.ToString();
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(htmlToConvert);

        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 0f, 0f);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
        pdfDoc.Open();

        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();

        string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

        return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", string.Format("{0}.pdf", fileName));
```

In **ABCDFORM** is a my view,I am working on MVC.and
am create **ABCDFORM** as html file.

I need add html checkbox,radiobutton in pdf

Comment: Find a library that does it for you.

Comment: i already find  but its not working

Comment: What code are you using and in what way is it not working. “Not working” means you have made no effort to understand the issue.

Comment: Please help....i edit my question am change structure

Comment: Again.... what way is it not working? Do you get an error? Does it create a PDF but without checkboxes?

Comment: Is this the class you are using? https://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/using-c-and-itextsharp-to-create-a-pdf/  You're probably going to have to pay for a PDF converter that includes textboxes etc.

Comment: Perhaps this one will do it easier. Although it's paid it appears to do forms. https://www.gnostice.com/docs/pdfone_dot_net/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=Create_PDF_forms_in_an_ASP_NET_application.html

Comment: yes, it's create PDF but without checkbox in MVC. I am working on MVC with itextsharp

Comment: I have fix this issue,Thank for Help

Comment: That's wonderful. It would be fantastic if you could document it in an answer